# catkin package library link to the openCV library

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros, catkin

I have been losing my head over this for some time now. So I need to use the opencv in a ros melodic  package built by the catkin on the Ubuntu 18.04. The idea is to make a package which is actually just a library and this library using all the regular ros packages (image_transport, cv_bridge, roscpp, rospy, std_msgs, genmsg, tf, actionlib_msgs, actionlib ). 
Just to let you know, I have 2 opencv installed, the openCV 3.2 in the `usr/share` and the openCV 4.3 in the `usr/local/share`, that is why I have specifically set the openCV_DIR to point to the 3.2 version.
I have tried to add `message` to the CMakeList.txt to print out the opencv_version, opencv_include_dir and opencv_libs and the version is `3.2.0`, include_dirs is `/usr/include;/usr/include/opencv` and libs are `opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_viz;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto`

in my `pkg_library` `CMakeList.txt` I have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pkg_libraries)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

set( OpenCV_DIR "/usr/share/OpenCV/" )

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(
  catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
          roscpp
          rospy
          std_msgs
          genmsg
          tf
          actionlib_msgs 
          actionlib

          sensor_msgs
          cv_bridge

          image_transport
          message_generation

)
find_package(
  OpenCV REQUIRED 
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES pkg_libraries
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs tf actionlib actionlib_msgs cv_bridge
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
            src/imageSaver.cpp 
)

target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

install(
  TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
install(
  DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
)
```

the compilation of the `pkg_libraries` with the `catkin_build` looks just fine, but later when I try to do `catkin_build` in the another package which includes the `pkg_libraries`, it fails with the error:

> libpkg_libraries.so: undefined reference to
>   `cv::imwrite(std::__cxx11::basic_string,
>   std::allocator > const&, cv::_InputArray const&,
>   std::vector > const&)'

Which I would say looks like the linker error, because I have used the `cv::imwrite` only in the `pkg_libraries`. and the package which reports the error includes only the `pkg_libraries`. So the `pkg_libraries` but it is obviously not linked properly, but it is built without errors.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the problem was because of the `pkg_libraries` is built like a shared library in which I have had another `.cpp` and `.h` which were using different `openCV` versions (default opencv 3.2) and I think the problem happened because by loading the `libpkg_libraries.so` I have made a conflict between `openCV` version. 
Anyway, now I have made separate libraries and it works as it suppose to work.

Thanks